# Open multiple excel files with user form

Tags: vba, excel

Write a code in vba that, Calling user form of one excel file to all the other 10 excel files without       having any reference in those 10 excel files.

It is displaying the output in current excel file but not in the destination files and shows the error as Userform is already shown and showing form modally is not possible

```
Private Sub Workbook_OnClick()
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim file As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pat As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDrive "C:"
    ChDir "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\John"
    'john is a folder on the desktop
    mypath = Range("B1").Value
    'mypath has the same value as chDir
    file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
    If (wb.Click) Then
        Application.Visible = False
        userform1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

chDir is mentioned because the default directory shown with the dir() function was C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ but the folder saved in desktop and that is C:\Users\Administrators\Desktop\John

Sir, It is displaying the run time error - 91 that is "Object variable or with block variable is not set" and highlighting the line "file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_OnClick()
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pat As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDrive "C:"
    ChDir "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\John"
    'john is a folder on the desktop
    mypath = Range("B1").Value
    'mypath has the same value as chDir
    file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Do While file <> ""
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
        If Not IsEmpty(wb) Then
            Application.Visible = False
            userform1.Show
        End If
        wb.Close
        file = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, It is displaying the run time error - 91 that is "Object variable or with block variable is not set" and highlighting the line "file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")"

Comment: My bad, I forgot to check how you declared your variables! you should have declared `file as string` because the `Dir()` will give you a string! Try the edit! ;)

Comment: @shrees : Plz take a minute to take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour (and accept the answers, as you are member for 2 months and haven't accepted one yet!). My last comment/edit should work just fine! ;)

Comment: It's again showing the error that is Run time - error '438' and Object doesn't support this property or method. and highlighting the line "if(wb.click) then" and if i change the code to "if(wb) then" the user form is not visible and the application opens as excel sheet         I accepted the answer sir...

Comment: Yup, the event `Click` as a specific event handler and you can't call it in another sub. So test, if the workbook has been set, try the edit! ;)

Comment: About answer acceptation, you have 4 questions at the moment, 2 with answers (this one, with my answer we are still working on and one with an answer that seems good to me but that you haven't accepted(clicked on tick right below the up/down votes so that it turn green))

Comment: Sir, Your are really good,  and thanks for working on those two questions. The answer is working but not as expected, the user form opened four times.  The folder "john" has 4 excel files in it  but, upon clicking the excel files they are not showing the user form . Instead the application opens

Comment: Glad I could help! (even if it is not exactly what you were expecting). If you want, you can post a new question with that working code and describe precisely what it is doing and what you want it to do, so that other will participate to improve it too! ;) Good luck and Enjoy SO! ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and fast response. Though the answer yet i got  but then the way you responded made me feel good. Once again thank you so much and good luck for all  your future projects. I have posted the question and the link is : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823450/how-to-call-a-user-form-from-one-excel-file-to-all-the-other-excel-files-of-a-fo"