# Call from one file a UserForm in another

Tags: vba, excel, userform

> Write VBA code that calls a UserForm of one Excel file to all the other Excel files present in a folder called `john` and the master Excel (consists of the following code and the user form) is present in a different location:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_OnClick()
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pat As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDrive "C:"
    ChDir "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\John"
    'john is a folder that consists of the excel files 
    mypath = Range("B1").Value
    'mypath has the same value as chDir
    file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Do While file <> ""
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
        If Not IsEmpty(wb) Then
            Application.Visible = False
            userform1.Show
        End If
        wb.Close
        file = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

The code is pulling the UserForm on the master Excel file instead of the Excel files present in `john` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workbook which contains the UserForm that you want to display should also have a procedure which displays the form.  You will need to call *this* procedure to display the userform.  It can be a function or a sub, I prefer function because then you can return a success/failure for error-handling.

In the UserForm workbook, you'll add a procedure like this in Module1 (or any module, but you'll need to reference this later):

```
Public Function ShowTheForm(Optional Modal As Boolean = False)
    'API to display a userform in THIS workbook, from another workbook

     On Error Resume Next
     UserForm1.Show IIF(Modal,vbModal,vbModeless)
     ShowTheForm = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Then, in the workbook which is trying to call this form open, you will need to invoke the `ShowTheForm` procedure, like so:

```
Do While file <> ""
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
    If Not IsEmpty(wb) Then
        Application.Visible = False
        Application.Run("'" & wb.Name & "'!Module1.ShowTheForm")
    End If
    wb.Close
    file = Dir()
Loop
```

Because you've given `ShowTheForm` as a function with a return value, you can trap errors, for example:

```
If Not Application.Run("'" & wb.Name & "'!Module1.ShowTheForm") Then
    MsgBox "Unable to display..."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Modified/enhanced based on the general logic provided here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-do-you-open-userform-in-another-workbook/e97b2c06-2a79-4cef-89bc-4f67b0f3c03a?db=5&auth=1

**NOTE**

I think `IsEmpty` is not the appropriate test on a workbook object, you may want to look in to that. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that line, but I'm almost certain it's not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: I didn't tought of the `Run`, nicely done anyway! ;)

Comment: Cheers @R3uK I was surprised that your method didn't work, because at a glance it looks like it *ought* to.

Comment: Same here! I thought it would work but hadn't time to check it!

Comment: Comment from OP posted on my answer : Sir David, you are asking to keep the reference in another workbook(the workbook that calls the user form) but my concern is that the code and the user form should be from the master excel file without giving any reference in any other workbooks (that are present in john folder)

Comment: @R3uK thanks, I'm not quite sure I understand OP's comment but OP has accepted this answer, so whatever s/he was inquiring about, seems to have resolved it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, how to **reference an UserForm from a workbook** :

```
Workbooks("Book1.xls").VBProject.VBComponents.Item("UserForm1")
```

this is working, but I can't manage to use `.Show` method :

```
Sub UFtest()
Dim UF_test As Object
    Set UF_test = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("UserForm1")
    UF_test.Show
End Sub
```

Here is your full code :

```
Private Sub Workbook_OnClick()
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pat As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDrive "C:"
    ChDir "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\John"
    'john is a folder that consists of the excel files
    mypath = Range("B1").Value
    'mypath has the same value as chDir
    file = Dir(mypath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Do While file <> ""
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
        If Not IsEmpty(wb) Then
            Application.Visible = False
            wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("UserForm1").Show
        End If
        wb.Close
        file = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Object doesn't support this propery or method, even with VB Extensibility reference.

Comment: @DavidZemens My bad! Corrected it, but can't manage to show the UF, any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a handle on the UserForm object, you have a handle on the VBComponent, which doesn't have a `.Show` method.

Comment: R3uK -- posted my solution below :)

Comment: Thank you so much....  But am not getting the required output. I hope only by looking into the screen shots of excel file it will be possible for us  to get the desired results. If you prefer to screenshots i can forward it to you and i don't have the email id's .please do the needful and by that i will be greatfull to you

Comment: sir R3uk, thank you so much for being taken part in this.

Comment: Sir I want to attach the screen shots then it will be useful to rectify the error and get  the result. Please do the needful

Comment: Sir waiting for your reply and how the project works i have explained in the above statements with attached screen shots. Definitely by spending few mins, my problem will be resolved that(problem) was there since four weeks.

Comment: My solution doesn't work, I'm gonna delete it. @DavidZemens : Can you explain to OP how yours works? If you understood something... Apparently he posted an answer with another profile... :/

Comment: Sir, I have given brief explanation in another web site and please check it. and the following is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914349/the-aim-of-the-project-is-to-assign-the-test-store-the-given-answers-in-master