# VBA Catching a userform event from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering how can i use vba code in "workbook1" to catch a user form "USRFRM.activate" event from another "workbook2".
so when the "USRFRM" is opened in Workbook2 a vba code is triggered in Workbook1 to click a button "BTTN1" on "USRFRM".
Note: i don't want to add or modify any code in workbook2, all my code and events handler need to be added in workbook1.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be way easier to implement such a thing on the same workbook. What is your objection against adding code there?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that unless you have UDF's/Class in `Workbook2` which allows you access to the form in `Workbook2`. I know you said you don't want to amend `Workbook2` but if you do get stuck and are able to amend that workbook, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823450/call-from-one-file-a-userform-in-another

Comment: Yes, it's easier to do it manipulating in "Workbook2". but the challenge is to do it from "Workbook1" only. Please help me solving this!

Comment: Unless you can change Workbook 2, you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, i know it's difficult but i believe it's can be done somehow. i will continue trying to solve it, and hopefully we can come up with a solution together. any suggestions or ideas  are welcome.

Comment: But why can't you just edit workbook 2's code? And perhaps there is an entirely different work around possible, if we know the real problem here.

Comment: I can edit Workbook2 code, but i don't want to do it this way. i just wanted to do it exactly as i asked above without touching WB2 code.

Comment: You can use API calls to hook the window messages, but you can't actually hook the Userform_Activate message per se, and of course this approach won't work for any other userform events.