# Reference UserForm.TextValue1 from VB code query

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, userform

i have a pre-created xlsm workbook that has inside of it some userforms that i'd like to set with values from some VB code. So I can access, open and show the workbook everything is going fine there but I'm having an issue in getting the syntax/terminology correct for interactibg with userforms.

my code looks something like this:

```
Dim wb as Object = getworkbook(handle, workbookname)
'i now have a workbook i can manipulate
'here i've left out a series of worksheet calls that happen and some other macro calls which I dont believe are relevant
'now i would like to reference the form that was named 'UserForm1' and in that form there are multiple text boxes with various titles so we'll just go with the first one 'TextBox1'.
' so i am trying to reference UserForm1.TextBox1 and set it to 'abcd'

'try 1 
wb.UserForm1.TextBox1 = "abcd"
'gives public member userform1 on type workbook not found

'try 2
wb.UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = "abcd"
'gives public member userform1 on type workbook not found

'try 3
'saw this on windows site but i dont get the syntax of calling them controls                     
'so im not confident in exactly how this was supposed to work
For Each Control in UserForm1.Controls
    Control.Visible = True
Next Control
'this was just to make it visible but it didnt work, i get compile errors of 
'UserForm1 not accessible maybe due to its protectionlevel.
```

now ive spent a while looking for solutions and i can find multiple references to VBA to VBA calls and hundreds of articles on calling other elements of a VBA project from VB but i can't seem to find anything particular on referencing userforms from a VB project.

Im guessing on my work so far that userforms 'dont exist' at run time and i need to create an object of it to manipulate from the VB code but i can't find the syntax of how to reference userforms correctly.

anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: small clarification GEtWorkbook() is a predefined task sorry for not provising clarity on that basically it opens a target workbook at instance handle and workbook name includes filepath as well as name together to point to a workbook.

Comment: Have you seen this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823450/call-from-one-file-a-userform-in-another)? I believe it may be a similar problem.

Comment: What's `getworkbook()`? Why aren't you doing it the straight forward way: `dim wb as Workbook` and then `set wb=Workbooks.open("File path")`

Comment: sorry its a method of code in the library im using, getworkbook() must look strange but in fact it is opening a workbook in handle and workbookname is actually filepath & name concat'd together. sorry for confusion

Comment: @Mistella this is pretty good i might consider this a workaround but i am not operating from another workbook i have an instance of running VB code connected to the singgular open workbook that contains the userform and i would like the vb code to interact with the userform. I will explore the workbook to workbook option and see how it works but first im going to explore passing values from VB to workbook form

Comment: @DexterWhelan, I misunderstood your question. Userforms are objects, and ideally you don't want to be dealing with a default instance. (I've seen some good examples, but I don't remember where right now.) To be able to interact with a control, a instance of the userform needs to be initialized. Usually, `.Show` on a default instance will also cause the initialization before showing the userform. However, since it's sounding like you want to interact with it before it's shown; it would probably be helpful to interact with a declared instance instead of the default.

Comment: Found a couple of links that might be helpful: [RubberDuck blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) and [yoursumbuddy.com](https://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `wb.UserForm1.TextBox1`.  Instead use this:

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = "abcd"
```

To make all controls on a UserForm Visible use this in the `UserForm_Initialize` Event:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ctrl as Control

For each ctrl in UserForm1.Controls
     If Typename(ctrl) = "TextBox" then
         ctrl.Visible = True
     End If
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: I've plugged this into my vb code but it's telling me UserForm1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. I guess this is saying at compile time the UserForm1 needs to be made visible somehow.

Comment: this would need to be in the `UserForm_Initialize` event.

Comment: Within a form's code module you should always loop via the `Me` particle referring to the current instance thus using `For each ctrl in Me.Controls` instead of referring to the Userform's default instance only  :-) @ZackE