# Copy data from specified excel file to word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

can someone please help - I am using this code to copy the data from excel to word:

```
Sub CreateRapport()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True

Sheets("Rapport").Activate
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E76")

Rng.Copy

With wd.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
    .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
    .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
    .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
    End With
    End Sub
```

What would I need to modify in the code to copy the data from a specified Excel file e.g. "C:\Book.xlsx" (not ThisWorkbook)? I am a newby in VBA so any hints would help. 
Thanks!

Comment: I would like to only specify the folder where the excel files are stored (not specific files), so data can be directly copied from them to Word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateRapport()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True

Dim wBK as WorkBook
Set wBK = Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx")

wBK.Sheets("Rapport").Activate
Set Rng = wBK.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E76")

Rng.Copy

With wd.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
    .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
    .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
    .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.
For some reason, I am getting an error saying 'the file cannot be found', although its there and I can open it from the specified location.

Is there a way to specify the folder with many excel files, from which I want to copy some cells?

Comment: Take a look at this, you'll see the `Dir` function that allow you to go through specific files in a folder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730417/open-multiple-excel-files-with-user-form/33730522#33730522